# What is the best way to get this TSQL Pivot to work

Tags: t-sql, pivot

I want to pivot a results set that only ever has 2 rows and a fix number of columns, where my ROWS are now my columns and my Columns are my Rows. Is this a PIVOT/UNPIVOT.

I want to pivot the following result from this

```
myPointer   f1   f2   f3   f4   f5
Start        0   19   20   21   22
End         18   19   20   21   24
```

To this

```
Stage    Start    End
f1        0        18
f2       19        19
f3       20        20
f4       21        21
f5       22        24
```

TIA for the help

Comment: This is a full table transpose, the duplicate should show you how to do this.

Comment: well, since I didn't use 'table transpose', I guess I just learned something new.  Thanks for the help.